# Hyperlink within prism, code tag

Tags: javascript, html, prism.js

I have the following in my html template:

```
<pre>
<code class="language-markup">
    {% filter force_escape %}
    <Item>
        <MarkUp><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></MarkUp>
        <Normal>Hello</Normal>
    </Item>
    {% endfilter %}
</code>
</pre>
```

I want it to markup the language (I'm using prism for that) but also hyperlink for the "Google" item.

Here is how it should look:

[image]

And clicking the word "Google" will open that link.

But here is how it currently looks:

[image]

Furthermore, the word "Google" is not clickable -- nothing within the `<code>` tag is linked.

How would I accomplish the above with prism?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The code tag removes all flow content from it. So an anchor inside a code block will never be executable. It only renders as text, stripped of markup powers. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-code-element

Comment: Prism appears simply to be a syntax highlighting library for code blocks, it wont remove the `code` tags function, which is to not render any internal markup.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I see -- thanks for the answer and tips here. Is there a way to use prism (or another library) without using the `<code>` tag?

Comment: You could try and see if Prism will render in an input element, like a textarea? Maybe even a div would work. I'm not sure, give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism seems to have a plugin for exactly this. You can download it here: http://prismjs.com/plugins/autolinker/. You can use this format:

```
[Text you want to see](http://url-goes-here.com)
```